# switching shape memory valves with microcontroller using NPN transistors

Tags: arduino, switches, npn, teensy

I am using a standard NPN transistor-as-a-switch set-up to use a Teensy 4.0 to switch a bunch of shape memory valves (valves controlled by a wire that changes shape when heated by a current). I have previously got some advice here on the use of a buck converter set-up to run this, but this did not work out well so I decided to go this simpler route and accept the ~0.35W power waste in the 8.2 Ohm resistor (2W type).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDYpBS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I connected the "Teensy DIO" point directly to the 3.3V DC power source, the transistor switches fine, giving the desired .25A current required to the SMV. When I instead set the Teensy DIO to High as in the circuit, I only get a 0.05A current, and the voltage at the Teensy channel is only .8V, with a current flow from the Teensy at 0.5mA. when disconnected from the circuit the channel goes to 3.3V when set to high, so the Teensy seems fine. Does anyone know why this set-up does not work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

(3.3V-0.6(=Vbe))/1k = 2.7mA
Output = 50mA   Ic/Ib= 18.5 which is expected as hFE reduces near 10% at saturation but is typ. rated at hFE=10.

Design for worst-case Ic/Ib=10  thus **Ib = 25mA, Rb ~ 100~120 Ohms**

### update

5.5V logic is typically 50 OHms +25% here operating at 3.3V,  ESR or RdsOn may be on the higher tolerance side.  PIO = 25 mA Abs. max so if tolerances are slim, reduce to 22mA (3.3-0.65V)/22mA = use 120 only

The RdsOn is standard for all 5.5V max logic  [but given as ESR=60 max on p35 of 49](https://www.cypress.com/file/416481/download) but uncertain if that is for 5V so even if +50% or 75 Ohms is used, 25mA generates only 50mW.

for a given Vdd, RdsOn= Vol/Iol , (Vdd-Voh)/Ioh

### 2nd update

---

On 2nd thought you can use a 2nd bigger transistor (to reduce T) in a Darlington configuration and reduce the waste power of the 8.2 to allow 0.7V extra drop of the Darlington 240mA to 5.6 Ohms with two 10 to 12 Ohm R’s in parallel as it dumps over 300mWto 350mW.

Comment: Ib 25mA might be borderline for a T4. Maybe a darlington configuration might be better?

Comment: Ib= 50mA is the rating for Vce(sat) =0.7max @ 500mA Borderlne? explain your thinking. (D'ton=worse with only 3.3V

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear indeed. I might be wrong, but Ib needs to be supplied by the Teensy pin. The IMXRT datasheet is very vague, but sourcing/sinking 25mA seems to be on the high side.

Comment: What is the (Vdd-Voh)/Ioh=RdsOn and Pd of CMOS driver?  25mA is rated for =Vdd/2 logic levels, but here only needs to be >>25mA * RdsOn

Comment: True Abs. Max is 25mA for PIO but ESR = 60 Ohm max so Pd= 37.5mW (max) is not a threat.

Comment: yes the Cypress specs are obscure in this area and simple logic is rated for 32mA for wire bonds so it is not a thermal issue, yet all 1.7~5.5V logic max have similar ESR

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've played around with different R1 values, but even at a 100Ohm R1 the current to the SMV is still ~0.05A

Comment: Report all components and voltages please

Comment: Ok, so in the configuration with the Teensy, as shown in the diagram, R1=100Ohms, R2=8.2Ohms (2W type), transistor is BC337 A011. power is supplied by benchtop power supply, signal from Teensy 4.1 on channel 23. in this configuration, when I set channel 23 to high, the current draw from the power supply is 23mA at 3.3V. the measured voltage from channel 23 to ground is 0.71V. the current at R1 is 0.11mA. at R2 the current is 22.7mA.

Comment: When instead of the teensy control I switch to connecting this point to the 3.3V positive lead of my power supply, I get 280mA at the power supply at 3.3V, and 18.5mA at R1

Comment: Thanks Tony, the Darlington configuration works! I am still a bit at a loss why the original solution does not work, since the current from the teensy is well below the limit.

Comment: Looking further into this it seems a better solution here is to use a MOSFET, which reduces the number of components and doesn't cause any trouble with the t4 either.

Comment: Better depends on your criteria . Cost of MPSA13 are pennies compared to a FET with Vth=1V and RdsOn of 0.1 is about 0.85$ (1). Number of components is still small and can be done without a PCB with THT

Comment: re MOSFET: I often use a irlm6344 to directly connect to Teensy 3V3 pins. 
https://octopart.com/irlml6344trpbf-infineon-65874984?r=sp . Works without issue so far. Only external part I'm using is a 100k resistor from gate to gnd. It is good for 30V 5A and comes in a tiny SOT23 package.

Comment: BTW: you can also PWM the pin on the Teensy (analogWrite())  to avoid the losses in R2

Comment: Yes assuming OP can use SMD